# Replace the part of the path by string in specific file type in a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In `U:\mtproject\obj\` folder and sub-folders having `*.def` files. I need to get those file paths and print in the command prompt.
but before print I need to replace the  `U:\mtproject\obj\` part by `E:\backupDir\DefBackup\`.

Here is what I tried and

```
set objdir=U:\mtproject\obj\
set backupdir=E:\backupDir\DefBackup\

for /r %objdir% %%f in (*.def) do (     
        set new_def_path =  %backupdir%!%%f:%objdir%=!
        echo %new_def_path%     
)
```

It just shows this output. I feel like some issue in the syntax of the string replacement. Any idea what is wrong?

```
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
```

Comment: Ah, the classic delayed expansion trap. Add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to the start of your script and change `%new_def_path%` to `!new_def_path!`

Comment: what is the different between %x% and !x! ?

Comment: Batch variables get replaced at runtime, so instances of %whatever% get replaced with their actual values, while !whatever! variables maintain their quality of being actual variables and are read by batch as literally %whatever% instead of their values. (Note that this is a bit of an oversimplification.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) use delayed expanison (as SomethingDark already mentioned)

b) remove the spaces whith your `set` commands or the spaces will be part of the variablename or value.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set objdir=U:\mtproject\obj\
set backupdir=E:\backupDir\DefBackup\

for /r %objdir% %%f in (*.def) do (     
        set new_def_path=%backupdir%!%%f:%objdir%=!
        echo !new_def_path!     
)
```

short demonstration of the [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

(interesting: you already use delayed expansion. Just do it consequent)